# How to return zero's if ee.Reducer.count() returns empty image?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have an algorithm that is computed using 2 ImageCollections over many areas and timeframes. When the algorithm is finished I export the results in an image, and I add 2 bands that tally the number of pixels from each ImageCollection the final result was based on. I do this using `ee.Reducer.count()` as follows:

```
var s2toa = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
                  .filterBounds(roi)
                  .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2016-01-01');

var nPixels = s2toa.select('B2')
                   .reduce(ee.Reducer.count())
                   .rename('nPixels');

print(nPixels);
```

However, it occasionally happens that no images are available at a given location within the timeframe of interest. In these instances the above approach returns an empty image:

```
var s2toa = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
                  .filterBounds(roi)
                  .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2014-01-01');

var nPixels = s2toa.select('B2')
                   .reduce(ee.Reducer.count())
                   .rename('nPixels');

print(nPixels);
```

In these instance, I would like to replace the empty image by an image of zeros, so that I can log the fact that zero pixels from that collection were used. Is there a way to do this programmatically? Perhaps there is something easy I have not thought of...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround for now. I've figured out that if I merge a dummy image with the empty ImageCollection `s2toa`, then I can use `ee.Reducer.count()` to return a value of 1 for all pixels, and subsequently subtract 1 to get zeros everywhere:

```
var s2toa = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
              .filterBounds(roi)
              .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2014-01-01');

var dummyImg = ee.Image(0).clip(roi).rename('B2');

var nPixels = s2toa.select('B2')
                   .merge(dummyImg)
                   .reduce(ee.Reducer.count())
                   .subtract(1)
                   .rename('nPixels');

print(nPixels);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/049eca7cfdd36945b4e736b1614d150a

A bit hacky, but it works... Open to more elegant alternatives!

Answer (score 1):

Specially if you are not mapping over collections you can use ee.Algorithms.If()
For example:

```
var s2toa = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
              .filterBounds(roi)
              .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2016-01-01');
//check if col is empty
var size = s2toa.size()

var nPixels = s2toa.select('B2')
                   .reduce(ee.Reducer.count())
                   .rename('nPixels');

var img = ee.Algorithms.If(size.neq(0), nPixels, ee.Image(0).rename('nPixels'))

print(img)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution, I think this is great and uses a logic I am more accustomed to. I have avoided any if else type logic in earth engine code so far because I found it didn't work as expected... but in this case it seems solid. I think it just doesn't work for any pixel-based operations.